# Gradle build/clean cuts off network and machine hangs

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

This problem has started recently, as soon I build or clean, my machine hangs and network is cut off, I have to restart machine to work on it.
It is happening without opening android studio, if I do a `./gradlew clean` from command prompt, still faced same issue
I had this issue previously, so I checked out repo at new location.

I'm using macbook pro v12.2

Android studio 2021.1.1 Patch 2